UID format for inline VCALENDAR events sent to gmail
I'm trying to programmatically send an e-mail containing an embeddded ICS/VCalendar event.
I've successfully created the MIME body as multipart/alternative and embedded the text/calendar data containing my VEVENT:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:AF81625E547AD981B4980F424ECBC28CD34219043596DA27CB05483BD5E95D8B998B1A
 1A1108E0250B6A239AA08CB6B50286EEC37F78FCFA
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20240906T071555Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Stockholm:20240907T110000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Stockholm:20240907T113000
SUMMARY:Test message
TRANSP:OPAQUE
LOCATION:somewhere
DESCRIPTION:Test message
ORGANIZER;CN="Jane Doe":mailto:jane.doe@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN="John Doe":MAILTO:john.doe@gmail.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

However, when receiving the message in Gmail, the embedded event is not detected as a calendar event (the Gmail message does not automatically place a calendar item on top of the message), instead it's just an .ics attachment (which works, but Gmail does not automatically place an interactive calendar event UI at the top of the message).

I then sent a calendar invite from Outlook to the same Gmail address, which produces a proper calendar event in Gmail:

So I started to compare the differences between the two.
It turns out it's the format of the UID field that causes Gmail to display or NOT display the calendar event properly. But I could not find any documentation of this field. The RFC recommends a random hex string of sufficient length (see e.g. https://icalendar.org/New-Properties-for-iCalendar-RFC-7986/5-3-uid-property.html), but when I generate a random 56 byte hex string, it does NOT work. However, when using the exact UID generated by Outlook (which is also 56 bytes but starts with 040000....), it DOES work:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000CC58C4FCFCFEDA0100000000000000
 00100000007055B4790D03D64D85A2B528AF8949EF
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20240906T071555Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Stockholm:20240907T110000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Stockholm:20240907T113000
SUMMARY:Test message
TRANSP:OPAQUE
LOCATION:somewhere
DESCRIPTION:Test message
ORGANIZER;CN="Jane Doe":mailto:jane.doe@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN="John Doe":MAILTO:john.doe@gmail.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Even replacing one single byte in the UID produced by Outlook ruins it (e.g. replacing the last EF with E0), so it seems to me that the UID field is in a very specific format (like a built-in checksum?) - although I cannot find anywhere what this format is. How do I create a UID which Gmail considers valid so that the event is displayed?
